# An error has occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS connection

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, weblogic11g

Getting below error with MQ(Message Queue), how to resolve this?

```
Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with
this connection has occurred. An error has occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS
connection. Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
```

Caused by [1] -->

```
Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
```

Caused by [3] -->

```
Message : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive
from host '/xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
(emb701t7.dci.bt.com)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=/xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
(emb701t7.dci.bt.com),4=TCP]
```

Please take me forward.

Comment: Which version of WebSphereMQ client are you using? Is it on the same level as on WebSphereMQ server? Maybe this link might help you: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV00348

Comment: We are using  WebSphereMQ Version:7.0.1.3

Comment: Do you use WebSphereMQ classes for Java or JMS? Do you use channel send exits on WebSpherMQ server side and XA transactions? If the answer is yes, please take a look at the link above: there is a bug in WebSphereMQ 7.0.1 that is fixed in PTF 7.0.1.6.

Comment: we do use JMS and we use channel

Comment: We are using websphereMQ client version:7.0.1.3 and WebSphereMQ server version:7.0.1.9, is the problem because of different versions??

Comment: Please try to replace WebSphereMQ client with the same version 7.0.1.9. The link I mentioned before explains this error is fixed in 7.0.1.6 and later.

Comment: The link points to a version difference between MQ and Process Server also using channel exits and the XA Extended Transactional Client.  There is nothing in the post that mentions *any* of these dependencies.  What IBM *does* say is that any supported version of MQ client will work with any supported version of MQ server.  So server/client mismatch is a red herring.

Comment: However, as you can see [here](http://iopt.us/1NhccXR) MQ v7.0.x is *not* supported and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21960691) that the last Fix Pack is 7.0.1.13.  The QMgr is running code from 2012 and the client code dates back to 2010.  The 2.0.1.13 code is last month.  That's a lot of fixes.  Given the number of JMS and the two WebLogic fixes in the later Fix Packs, if you can't move to a supported client, at least get to 7.0.1.13.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error and its resolved now!

As Magic Wand mentioned in the comment, below error comes up if you have a lower version of MQ jar i.e if your MQ jar version is 7.0.1.5 or below

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host
```

This bug has been fixed in IBM MQ version 7.0.1.6 or higher as mentioned here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV00348

Add the newer version of below ibm.mq jars and make sure you have the additional jars too mentioned below:

```
com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar 
com.ibm.mq.jar 
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar    
com.ibm.mqbind.jar 
com.ibm.mqjms.jar 
fscontext.jar    
jms-1.1-20020430.jar
providerutil.jar
```

Comment: Or better yet actually use a version that is current and supported by IBM in the event you run into problems.   7.0.1.x has been out of support since 2015.  8.0 and later are the only currently supported versions.  8.0 goes out of support in less than 2 years,  better to use 9.0 which has not had an announced end of support. 9.1 will be released by the end of this month as well.

Comment: I would have but this is an enterprise project and they usually take time to upgrade the stack

Answer (score 2):

The TCP connection between the MQ client running in weblogic and the MQ Queue Manager channel process is being broken unexpectedly (that is what the return code 2009 means). This could be down to a number of issues such as the queue manager being killed, the channel process exiting for some reason, a firewall killing the connection etc. Have a look on the MQ queue manager error logs for issues with the channel process at the same time. Take a note of how often the error message occurs i.e. is the first error 2 hours after the weblogic server starts.

You could take a network trace to see how the TCP connection is being closed and by who.

Comment: TCP connection is not closed we are able to connect to host by TCP

Comment: You mean you have verified that the individual tcp connection established between the clime and server is not closed? So when you do a netstat you can still see the same port being used on the client side and the connection is still established?